# Graphic Adapter problem in Assembly with vista

Tags: assembly, windows-vista, adapter, graphic

When I want to switch to GA in Assembly with Vista it gives me a fatal error and it simply says "I don't support 16bit GA".
What should I Do?

Comment: You may want to provide more information, especially source code and which assembler and/or compiler you used.

Answer (score 0):

Some assemblers output 16 bit instructions by default. With [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/) you'd have to use the *bits* directive to change that, for example:

```
bits 32
xor eax, eax
```

If the *bits* directive in the above example would have been omitted, then the output would have been "xor ax, ax" (in machine code).